# Could not load type from assembly in Mono

Tags: dll, mono

I'm running a pre-built application using Mono, and it runs alongside a DLL in the same directory (`mysql.data.dll`). When I run the application with Mono, I get this error:

```
Could not load type 'Snowlight.Storage.SqlDatabaseClient' from assembly 'Snowlight, Version=0.1.0.35857, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,Snowlight.Storage.SqlDatabaseClient].Init (Int32 capacity, IEqualityComparer`1 hcp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,Snowlight.Storage.SqlDatabaseClient]..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Snowlight.Storage.SqlDatabaseManager.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Snowlight.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Judging by `<filename unknown>`, I am assuming this happens because the DLL it requires isn't found, so how would I get the application to recognize it and use it?

Answer (score 18):

Try running it like this from a terminal:

```
export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug
export MONO_LOG_MASK=asm
mono --debug yourapp.exe
```

Now every assembly lookup will be printed to the terminal, so you'll be able to find out what's being looked for where.